# How many times can an even number be divided by two before it becomes odd?

Tags: algorithm, math, bit-manipulation

I am trying to figure out a way to figure out how many times an even number can be divided by two before it becomes odd. I.E. 100/2 = 50 => 50/2 = 25. So 100 can be divided by two twice. before it becomes odd. I am looking for all even numbers that are NOT powers of two.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math.

Comment: Think of the number in binary and count the number of zeros at the end.

Comment: it is math but i believe the answer can be found using bit manipulation

Comment: You could use `x & -x` to get the rightmost 1, and then you solve it for just powers of two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's two questions.

1. I am trying to figure out a way to figure out how many times an even number can be divided by two before it becomes odd. I.E. 100/2 = 50 => 50/2 = 25. So 100 can be divided by two twice. before it becomes odd.

Convert the number binary and count the 0s before the first 1. Each time you dive by 2 you loose a zero and when a 1 is in the "first" position you've got an odd number.

1. I am looking for all even numbers that are NOT powers of two.

Again, looking at the binary, powers of 2 have only one bit set and odd numbers have the 1 bit set. So anything with multiple bits set AND not the 1 bit is your answer.